# Accessing SSM variables with Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I would like to use [SSM Parameters in Serverless Variables](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1.22.0/).

Following the docs, I ran this command:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name foo --value bar --type SecureString
```

And I added this to my `serverless.yml`:

```
custom:
  foo: ${ssm:foo}
```

When I deploy, I get this warning however:

```
Serverless Warning --------------------------------------

  A valid SSM parameter to satisfy the declaration 'ssm:foo' could not be found.
```

How do I access this variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I needed to set the same region for both the serverless function, as well as the ssm variable assignment:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name foo--value bar --type SecureString --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 6):

if the parameter is a SecureString, you need to add ~true after the path to the parameter on the serverless.yml file, as explained here: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-variables-using-the-ssm-parameter-store

This will tell the framework to decrypt the value. Make sure that you have permissions to use the key used to encrypt the parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Check your IAM policy.  To get the parameters, the user doing the deployment needs access to SSM. This offers full access.  [See the docs to narrow it down a bit (ie: GetParameters, GetParameter).](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html)

```
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ssm:*"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "*"
  ]
```

Comment: To be clear, this is the IAM policy of the user you give to "sls deploy"

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the provider section in serverless.yml file

```
 iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action: 
    - "ssm:GetParameters"
  Resource: "*"
```

Answer (score -2):

to use SSM variables, you need to prefix `/aws/reference/secretsmanager/`

example

```
${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/${self:provider.stage}/service/mysecret~true}
```

Comment: I think in the context of serverless yaml, SSM by default does not mean secrets manager, so it is worth clarifying your answer. IF the secret is stored in secrets manager then your answer is correct per https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-using-the-ssm-parameter-store